# Invalid operands to binary expression ('double(*)(double' and 'double')

Tags: c++, numerical, newtons-method

I was trying to figure out the Newton's method to find the root of equation. And this bug came out and I couldn't handle it.

```
double fn(double n){
    return sin(n)+log(n)-1;
}

double f1n(double n){
    return cos(n)+1/n;
}

double operation(double n){
    n=n-fn/f1n;

    while(fn>0.000001){
        n=n-fn/f1n;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: fn and f1n are functions. You are dividing one function by another which makes no sense. You probably want to invoke those functions using fn(n) and f1n(n) and use the answers

Comment: ``n=n-fn/f1n;`` What do you try to achieve with dividing two memory addresses (the 2 functions)?

Comment: You *do* know how to call functions, don't you? Well obviously you do, as you do it in the code you show (like you call the `cos` or `sin` functions), why don't you do it with your own functions?

Comment: better to impose additional restrictions on the number of iterations, the algorithm will not always converge.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass `n` to your functions.

```
double operation(double n)
{
    n = n - fn(n) / f1n(n);
    while(fn(n) > 0.000001)
    {
        n = n - fn(n) / f1n(n);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks! I Get it!